# Need to get a list of available caption tracks for a youtube video

Tags: javascript, video, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm working on an app that will (hopefully) load a list of available closed caption tracks that are available for youtube videos. The only thing I could find was this url: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/captions/iVKCE9Vmg2k where I was supposed to add the video id (iVKCE9Vmg2k) at the end, but when i go there it requires a login. Is there any way of retrieving this list without the user having to log in? In this particular video there are English, Japanese, and Spanish translations. I would like to be able to load those options into a pulldown menu on my html page.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer. In this case I'd just use the url:
http://video.google.com/timedtext?type=list&v=iVKCE9Vmg2k
and it returns the xml file with the list in xml form.